# Passing file as parameter to shell script and iterating over columns of file

Tags: bash, shell

I want to pass file as parameter to my shell script and iterate over columns of file passed
Number of columns in file is not known in advance. I am using CSV file as input.
how can I do this in shell script?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41232/loop-through-tab-delineated-file-in-bash-script

I checked this link but did not get much idea..not well versed with shell scripting just know basics

Comment: You can use `awk`. Try it out from your linked answer.

Comment: Post more details perhaps.